# What is Siddha Kunjika Stotra?

Tags: scripture, parvati, goddess, devi, stotra

While reading i came across name of a Devi-Stotra called   "**Siddha Kunjika Stotra"(सिद्धकुन्जिका स्तोत्रं )** ,it's said that lord Shiva himself told this  stotra to godess parvati.

So  i would like to know -

**1) What is this Siddha Kunjika  stotram , What's the central theme , in which scripture this stotra is mentioned.?**

**2) What is the significance of the Siddha Kunjika Stotram?**

Comment: By reciting this stotra, it reveals hidden laws of nature ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Siddha Kunjika Stotra](http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/durga-saptashati/siddhakunjika-stotram/durga-saptashati-siddhakunjika-stotram.html) is recited before Chandi Patha or before reciting the Devi Mahatyam.

It is said that just by reciting this stotram the fruits of reciting the Devi Mahatyam are obtained.

And,if the stotram is not recited before Chandi Patha then the later recitation bears no fruit or bears less fruits.

Siddha Kunjika Stotram is composed by Lord Shiva Himself and is found in the **RudraYamala Tantra.**

> शिव उवाच शृणु देवि प्रवक्ष्यामि, कुञ्जिकास्तोत्रमुत्तमम्। येन
>   मन्त्रप्रभावेण चण्डीजापः शुभो भवेत॥१॥ न कवचं नार्गलास्तोत्रं कीलकं न
>   रहस्यकम्। न सूक्तं नापि ध्यानं च न न्यासो न च वार्चनम्॥२॥
>   कुञ्जिकापाठमात्रेण दुर्गापाठफलं लभेत्। अति गुह्यतरं देवि देवानामपि
>   दुर्लभम्॥३॥ गोपनीयं प्रयत्‍‌नेन स्वयोनिरिव पार्वति। मारणं मोहनं वश्यं
>   स्तम्भनोच्चाटनादिकम्। पाठमात्रेण संसिद्ध्येत्
>   कुञ्जिकास्तोत्रमुत्तमम्॥४॥
>
> Meaning-Shiva said-"O Parvati,hear the great prayer called Kunjika,by
>   recitation of which the recitation of Chandi Patha(Devi Mahatyam)
>   would become more powerful& auspicious.
>
> There is no need to recite Kavacham ,Argalam ,Kilakam and the Rahasya
>   Thrayam,Nor it is necessary to recite Suktam,Dhyanam,Nyasa neither is
>   a need for worship.
>
> **Just by reciting this stotra we would get the benefit of reciting the
>   Chandi Patha**.And,O Goddess,even the Gods don't know this secret
>   prayer....

And  the Stotra ends with"

> इति श्रीरुद्रयामले गौरीतन्त्रे शिवपार्वतीसंवादे कुञ्जिकास्तोत्रं
>   सम्पूर्णम्। ॥ॐ तत्सत्॥
>
> Meaning -Thus ends the Kunjika Stotra which is  found during a dialogue between Shiva & Parvati as found in 
>   **Gowri Tantra in the Rudrayamala.**

Verse 4 of the stotra states:

> गोपनीयं प्रयत्‍‌नेन स्वयोनिरिव पार्वति। मारणं मोहनं वश्यं
>   स्तम्भनोच्चाटनादिकम्। पाठमात्रेण संसिद्ध्येत्
>   कुञ्जिकास्तोत्रमुत्तमम्॥४॥
>
> Meaning-O Parvati you should make effort to keep it(this prayer)
>   secret as just by reciting it one can easily achieve (bad practices like)
>   murder(maarana),enchants(mohana), slavery(vasya),paralysing using repeated chants(stambhana) and sending away(ucchatana)
>   .

So,the above verse gives an account of what can be achieved by reciting the stotra.

Comment: Nice answer. There is also another version available in Damara Tantra: http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/siddhakunjikaa.html?lang=sa

Comment: Nice answer.However, these words- "can easily achieve murder,enchants, slavery"- need to be modified to- "can easily achieve to overcome murder , enchants, slavery",for  then the meaning will be lucidly conveyed.Thank you..

Comment: @UdayKrishna No.My translation is correct.Lord Shiva is telling Devi to keep it secret only because by reading this powerful stotra one can achieve bad practices like murder,slavery,stambham(paralysing) ,ucchatan etc.So,in effect Lord does  not want this stotra to be known to bad persons whose purposes are malefic.

Comment: Since the mantra is unlocked(siddha) it becomes all the more important to keep it away from bad peoples.

Comment: I agree, I understood clearly that this has got to do with tantra practices .Nothing is wrong in the translation and it is 10/10.But, since the Strotra is chiefly for overcoming bad effects, I am seeing it as "achieve to overcome".

Comment: Like I said, the translation is 10/10.